# Python dictionary average value function

Tags: python

Why the program does not want to calculate the average value from the dictionary?

```
grades = {}

def addGrade(grades):
    course = input("input course: ")
    grade = int(input("input grade: "))
    grades[course] = grade

def printGrades(grades):
    print("all grades:")
    for c, grade in grades.items():
        print(c + "\t" + str(grade))

def count(grades):
    n = len(grades.keys())
    print(n)

def printAverage(grades):
    print("average grade:" + sum(grades)/int(count))
```

Comment: How are you filling `grades`? Where are you calling your functions? What is `count`? To calculate the average, you should use `sum(grades.values())/len(grades)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add:

```
 count = len(grades.keys())
```

Because it is not defined in your function.

The correct version of your function is:

```
 def printAverage(grades):
      count = len(grades.keys())
      print("average grade:" , sum(grades.values())/count)
```

Comment: `count` is already `int`. No need to cast it.

Comment: also no need to count the keys, `len(dict)` already works just fine

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
sum(grades.values())
```

Otherwise it will be adding up all the `key`s instead of the values (grades).

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
grades = {}

def addGrade():
    course = input("input course: ")
    grade = int(input("input grade: "))
    grades[course] = grade

def printGrades():
    print("all grades:")
    for c, grade in grades.items():
        print(c + "\t" + str(grade))

def count():
    n = len(grades.keys())
    return n

def printAverage():
    print(f"average grade: {sum(grades.values()) / len(grades):.2f}")
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    number_of_courses = int(input('Enter number of courses: '))
    
    for _ in range(number_of_courses):
        addGrade()
    printAverage()
```

sample output:

[image]